# How to promote expats.se

Tags: discussion

I think we are a small but successful site with a number of core users who provide high quality answers to the questions we get. I think we also get some high quality questions. While bigger is not always better, I think we can stand to grow a little bit. What should we be doing to promote expats.se?

Comment: I'm not sure what all else we can do at this point. If you look at the most successful user-driven sites for immigration topics (one of which I'm also very active on), they tend to be message boards where discussions, and even debates, can carry on. This format is great for straightforward answers, even if the answer is 'we don't know', but it's not so great for complicated situations and drawn out discussions. We have stuff in place for that obviously, but the comment/chat functionality is a primary driver here. Maybe expats could modify its presentation a bit to encourage that type of ....

Comment: ...interchange. Otherwise, as a Q/A site, it will be a challenge to grow at a much faster rate than we already are growing.

Answer (score 1):

Been thinking about this.  We're meeting quite [a few of the graduation criteria](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) - but where we're really not doing great is the answer rate.

It may help to have a drive to go through the unanswered questions, answering what we can, marking some as dupes where applicable, and also close those that are off topic, incomplete and so on. This should help boost us.

Questions per day will just come with growth, but solid answers will attract that growth.

Also finding related questions on, say, travel.SE, and linking to the expats site may help.

As a result, to track the uptick (hopefully) of answered questions, [I've started this meta post](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/318/97).

Answer (score 1):

I feel we should actively promote ourselves on the popular immigration forums. There is a few I know of and will list them here. The advantage for this site over others is, some of those discussions get long winded and hard to find the quick response one is looking for. The predictability of the UI here is good as well as the search is awesome

- Immihelp.com
- H1bwiki.com
- Reddit(will look for immigration related
  channels there)
- Quora forums

Comment: you may like https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/333/97 ;)