# Trending our answered percentage to 90% (succeeded!)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, statistics

I'd like to track this with the goal of getting the answer rate up to 90% (with rounding, at least), and as such will occasionally update below with updated stats.  Feel free to do this as well.

At time of writing (July 12, 2017) we have:

- [782 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [769 questions with no answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- a [76%ish answer rate, which puts us at 142nd overall](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network

Comment: Yesterday I just went through the answered but not upvoted list, and upvoted the answers that were good. We do seem to be lacking upvotes for both questions and answers on this site BTW

Comment: For the rest we either need to get answers, or check them if they are duplicates, my guess is we do have a fair amount of them already

Comment: Its up to 89% now. :)

Comment: @SztupY You might also consider using a reward system for good answers, like to [Latin SE](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/840), to promote answering and voting.

Comment: Good job everybody. Guess we need to stay on top of this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered |  Rank  |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| July 12th, 2017      |  782    |  769      | 76%       |  142nd | 
| July 14th, 2017      |  784    |  772      | 76%       |  143rd | 
| July 16th, 2017      |  775    |  760      | 77%       |  141st | 
| July 17th, 2017      |  771    |  756      | 77%       |  140th |     
| July 18th, 2017      |  762    |  748      | 77%       |  140th |     
| July 19th, 2017      |  760    |  743      | 77%       |  140th |     
| July 20th, 2017      |  743    |  728      | 77%       |  138th |     
| July 21st, 2017      |  734    |  726      | 78%       |  136th | 
| July 22nd, 2017      |  719    |  708      | 78%       |  131st |   
| July 23rd, 2017      |  710    |  690      | 79%       |  131st |     
| July 24th, 2017      |  688    |  671      | 79%       |  128th |     
| July 25th, 2017      |  666    |  652      | 80%       |  125th |     
| July 26th, 2017      |  652    |  637      | 81%       |  124th |   
| July 27th, 2017      |  639    |  621      | 81%       |  123rd |     
| July 28th, 2017      |  602    |  583      | 82%       |  117th |  
| July 29th, 2017      |  573    |  554      | 83%       |  115th |   
| July 30th, 2017      |  572    |  542      | 83%       |  116th |     
| July 31st, 2017      |  552    |  530      | 83%       |  115th |     
| August 1st, 2017     |  520    |  497      | 84%       |  108th |     
| August 2nd, 2017     |  485    |  463      | 85%       |  106th |     
| August 3rd, 2017     |  473    |  457      | 86%       |  105th |     
| August 4th, 2017     |  464    |  443      | 86%       |  104th |  
| August 5th, 2017     |  451    |  421      | 86%       |  102nd | 
| August 6th, 2017     |  449    |  412      | 86%       |  102nd |     
| August 7th, 2017     |  418    |  395      | 87%       |   98th |     
| August 8th, 2017     |  406    |  373      | 88%       |   97th | 
| August 9th, 2017     |  369    |  339      | 89%       |   91st | 
**| August 10th, 2017    |  346    |  322      | 90%       |   89th |**     
| August 17th, 2017    |  288    |  263      | 91%       |   83rd |     
| August 20th, 2017    |  262    |  241      | 92%       |   75th |     
| August 23rd, 2017    |  248    |  240      | 93%       |   72nd |
```

Comment: Man, that's a lot of work...

Comment: @JonathanReez one step at a time ;) My main hope is to get it to 90% answered so that [our area51 stats go green](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates).

Comment: @JonathanReez easiest way is to upvote answers that are in the queue, and look for subjective questions eg I found some "best insurance" etc questions yesterday. Also looking for ones where we asked a question of the OP and they've not replied - putting on hold as unclear.

Comment: Doing what I can. I figure if we each do 10 per day we could get it sorted out within a month.

Comment: Can only review 20 a day. I don't run into that limit very often!

Comment: @ouflak it's a new day now, get back to it ;)

Comment: Mark, you should also use your close vote privileges. Otherwise we won't get anywhere :/

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm doing one every time I log on, I don't want to overdo my powervote.  But we're making progress.

Comment: We have a lot of close votes with no comments. Please can everyone make sure to add a comment if close voting, to explain your reason and to try and help the OP.

Comment: Could there be some statistics on how many of those Qs get closed and how many answered? I see the number reducing but would be interesting to know why.

Comment: @mts have access to some of that in the 'top secret mod stats' (so can't share specifics). But I know I've answered about 14 in the last fortnight, and others are too.  It's been a long time without a cleanup - many of these would have been sorted out within a day on travel as unclear/off-topic, but they'd languished for quite a bit in the giant pile of unanswered questions.

Comment: Also everybody keep a look out for questions that have answers, especially in the comments. Just providing an answer will also build up our percentage, and in the long run probably will be better for the site with regards to search engines and such.

Comment: Yeah good work everyone. The only stat it needs to do better on is questions per day. 4.4 is low needs more than 5. Perhaps that can be a new goal? @MarkMayo Also when do we get to get out of beta?

Comment: @pal4life out of beta is up to SE, not us :/  We also need to improve answers per qusetion.

Comment: @pal4life added two new goal/challenges on meta to try and help this ;)