# Close votes - PLEASE leave a comment

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, close-reasons

I applaud those helping with the [big cleanup of 2017](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318/trending-our-answered-percentage-to-90-currently-83), but in the review / mod queue, we're seeing a LOT of questions with close votes and no comments, questions or clarifications.

If it's unclear, leave a comment explaining why it's unclear.  Just closing it does nothing to help the user.

I won't name names, but please can we all make an effort to help the users who are having their questions closed.

Comment: There are lots of threads [on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/show-the-reason-given-for-a-close-vote-before-the-question-gets-closed) that ask to display a canned comment so the user knows his question is bad even *before* there is 5 votes. I guess nobody cares enough. Maybe you could add some diamond weight behind one of them.

Comment: @nvoigt yeah that's been going on for years. But in the meanwhile, we can at least tell the OP ourselves. :/