# Goal: 10 Booster badges

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Currently we have only [two Booster badges](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) (awarded to the same person) earned on Expats! This is such a shame - it's an easy enough way to earn a badge if active on other platforms.  I'm going to create an answer below listing for posterity the first 10 people ever to earn the Boosterbadges.  If you'd like to make this list, start sharing some links on reddit, Facebook, twitter, wherever seems appropriate (without spamming of course)!

Answer (score 2):

## **[First 10 Boosters on Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster)**

1. March 19, 2014 - Mark Mayo
2. ?
3. ?
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?

Share a link now to join this list!